# how can I make arabic letters Connected

Tags: java, locale, arabic

I open a new game but I got a problem. when I write in the Arabic Characters/Letters in Arabic Language, it doesn't show me Connected words. I then edited something because it was inverse, first time it was - **م ك ي ل ع م ا ل س ل ا** and when I make an inverse it returns the string correctly but the words are not Connected, i.e. it's ***showing spaces in between the characters like - ا ل س ل ا م ع ل ي ك م; but it must be - السلام عليكم***

And refer these pics for know more info -

[image: this not mixed]
[image: this mixed and true]

And this my code
what i should do? if you need more info i will give you

```
StringBuilder rmessage = new StringBuilder(message);
rmessage.reverse();

message = rmessage.toString();
```

So, what should I do to remove spaces in between the Arabic characters & make it connected?

Comment: maybe you can try <p dir="rtl">Write this text right-to-left!</p> if you want to display this message on a web page

Comment: its in game not web thank

Comment: How do you display the string? Swing? Console? Other?

Comment: Try this `new String(message.getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));` assuming message = `السلام عليكم`.

Comment: You need to describe everything you're doing, from start to end. Notably, anything that requires you invert the order of your characters will fail, as the technology is not built that way.

Comment: thank you all ^_^ i will try and if anyone have solution send here pls :